# Is there a way to reference a class instance in a different file?

Tags: python, tkinter, package

I am making a package that will open an application in a tkinter window and allow the user to manipulate an image. The commands for the GUI are currently in a separate folder in the package than the file that initiates the application GUI. Many of the commands use attributes of the application instance, so they need to be able to access it. Before, I had all of the code in a single file and used global variables to achieve this. Now that the code is separated into files in different folders, is there a way that I can still access the application instance? Or do I need to have all of the code that references the instance in the same file?

Comment: Did you try `import`?

Comment: As in importing the GUI module into the command module?

Comment: You can import whatever you need, maybe you could provide more detail of the code, so it becomes clearer how your project is structured.

Comment: The file is totally irrelevant. Your python program could be running code who's source is all over your disk, indeed, it always does. Theoretically, the code could be on some server far away. This might sound pedantic, but it is important to understand, an instance doesn't actually live in some `.py` file, that is where the *source code is*, your instance lives *in memory*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks, that makes a lot more sense. I'm going to try importing the GUI module and see how that goes.

Comment: @a_guest My original code before packaging is almost 2,000 lines, and the references to the application instance are scattered through the whole thing, so I don't know if you still want to see it, or just a portion of it.

Comment: @JoshOlson I'd rather like to see the different modules of your application (e.g. `tree my_app`) as well as the interfaces of the modules, i.e. the part that accepts a reference to objects from other modules.